# is this good: calling a rest endpoint from varnish reverse proxy

Tags: java, caching, varnish

Currently we are building an app which does something and before doing something it always validates the  token send by the client by calling a different service i.e. authentication service. Now we are planing to use varnish reverse proxy. Even though we use varnish, it needs to call the authentication service to authenticate the token (it takes nearly 100 milisec to validate a token) before even returning the response.

So my question is is it proper to use varnish for this use case. Because varnish suppose to return the cached response blazingly fast manner if i tell varnish to call to authentication service to authenticate the token than it may not be proper. What you guys think about it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can probably do this in a vmod (https://www.varnish-cache.org/vmods), there are already some vmods for authenticating using ldap, so it can be done.

But if your verification takes ~100ms, and you want something fast, I would look to see if you can generate a token that you can check it's validity without contacting a slow service. Something that cryptographically signs some secret, some value that identifies the client (IP, username, ...) and an expiration date to generate a token that you can validate in the vcl during it's lifetime without contacting external services.